# how to get the response from local host api using ajax call juery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

i am not able to get the response from the local host api.
another approaches you have tried==adding header as well Access-Control-Allow-Headers = '*'

````
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){
      Approve()
    });
function Approve(){
        alert("hello")
        $.ajax({
        //url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api?Id=3?callback=?",
        url:"https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/all",  
        //jsonp: "callback",
       data:{},
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response); // server response
    }
});
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <input type="button" value="Approve"  onclick="javascript:Approve()" />
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: remove the cors url  (https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com) and enable the cors from backend and please share some details like what it shows after request in the network tab

Comment: i am getting  access below error:test1.html:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api?Id=3' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
jquery.min.js:4 GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/api?Id=3 net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: enable the cors from backend